# Varnish + Rails causes invalid authenticity tokens in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, thin, varnish

Here is my situation. I am testing out Varnish on my local box (I'm doing some stuff related to page caching that would be a big pain to push to staging every time). Everything works fine, except whenever I submit a form, I get an `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` exception.

Varnish is running on localhost at port 6081, and Thin is running on localhost at port 80. I get the exception when I try to use the site using port 6081.

Is there any way I can get around this?

Comment: Skipping verify_authenticity_token in development does the trick, but this seems hacky to me.

Comment: Upon further inspection: this doesn't solve the problem. Since (I'm assuming) the ports do not match, the session does not work properly. Thus, I cannot login on my local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the reason this was failing was my VCL file was clearing out *all* cookies on every request. Obviously, this would cause some issues with the authenticity token.

Silly fix for a silly problem :/

Comment: Is varnish caching your actions/views? Even setting the Cache-control on my rails controller vanish doesn't store the pages... they are all going with a MISS. I'm blaming the cookies, any idea?